# Coded UI Winlist Selection

Tags: listview, coded-ui-tests

I am working With Coded UI,when automating an application I need to select and item from winlist which have special characters like (parentheses, # etc), default SlectedItemsAsString() method is not working for this situation, I have found that giving the selection as string array worked with SelectedItems() method, Here is the example:

```
string templatename = item.Name;
String[] SelectedTempList = { templatename };
uILvwDetailsList.SelectedItems = SelectedTempList;
```

Does any one have better idea to select the winlist item with special characters using SelectedItemsAsString() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WinListItem.Selected() method.  The string, typically, is the name property in Coded UI list items.

```
            WinWindow form1 = new WinWindow();
        form1.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Form1";
        WinList list = new WinList(form1);
        list.SearchProperties[WinList.PropertyNames.Name] = "listBox1";
        WinListItem listItem = new WinListItem(list);
        listItem.SearchProperties[WinListItem.PropertyNames.Name] = "2 -WinListItem with special characters !@%";
        listItem.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.ExpandWhileSearching);

        listItem.Select();
```

Comment: Do you know a way to identify that any items exist in the Winlist without using Winlist.items property? because winlist.items property is slow when retrieving more that 1000 records from list.